# Jquery Javascript best way to check elements done appending

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements that are dynamically appended after an Ajax call. I am using a plugin that creates a lightbox click event for the anchors dynamically appended. It works fine except sometimes it says that the title is undefined. I realize this is because the plugin gets initiated before the title attribute is completely done appending to the DOM. I know of several ways to do this, but what is the BEST way to check that all these elements are completely appended?

Ajax call is already made and data parsed with this function (colorbox title is the one that evaluates to 'undefined' for only some):

```
function pageImages(images,_q){
    for(var i = 0; i < images.count; i++){
        $('#pageImages').append('<div class="pageImageItem"><a href="' + images.data[i]._clickurl + '" title= "' + images.data[i]._title + '">\
            <img src="' + images.data[i]._thumbnailUrl + '" alt= "' + images.data[i]._title + '"/>\
            </a><div class="hoverInfo"><a href="' + images.data[i]._clickurl + '"><h2>' + images.data[i]._title + '</h2><p>' + limitCharacters(images.data[i]._clickurl,40) + '</p></a></div></div>');
    }


    $(".pageImageItem a").colorbox({maxWidth:'95%', maxHeight:'95%', title: function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href'),
            title = $(this).attr('title');

        console.log(title);
        return '<h2>' + title + '</h2><a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + limitCharacters(url,40) + '</a>';
    }});


}
```

And here is a picture of what is happening (anchor highlighted is the element that clearly has a title attribute but is showing undefined in lightbox):
[image]

Comment: *"I realize this is because the plugin gets initiated before the title attribute is completely done appending to the DOM."* No, it isn't. The element is completely appended to the DOM before your `.append` call returns. The problem lies elsewhere. With the code you've shown, `$(this).attr('title');` will never return `undefined`. It could return `""`, though, if any of the `images.data[i]._title` properties is `""`. And it could return `"undefined"` (note the quotes) if any of the `images.data[i]._title` properties is `undefined` (or missing from `images.data[i]` entirely).

Comment: I'm not sure what it could be then. I'll attach a picture in my question of what is happening on the front end. If you have any idea let me know. Also, when I click on the anchor AGAIN often the title shows up correctly.

Comment: Mind posting the AJAX call?

Comment: what debugging have you done, have you tried tracing what's going on here, your code given really doesn't give us any insight into what might be going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the jQuery element find block in a timeout without timevalue. The timeout will wait for all javascript to be finished with all processes. Example:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".pageImageItem a").colorbox({maxWidth:'95%', maxHeight:'95%', title: function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href'),
            title = $(this).attr('title');

        console.log(title);
        return '<h2>' + title + '</h2><a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + limitCharacters(url,40) + '</a>';
    }});
});
```